# How to install fireplace mantel on stone fireplace

Tags: fireplace, stone

This is the stone fireplace in our house:

[image]

[image]

The rocks are quite big and the surface is very uneven.
We want to install this stone fireplace surround:

[image]

I have several questions:

1. I assume I have to cut the surface of the stone to make it at least even / flat and then "cement" the fireplace surround into it? Is that the right approach?
2. What kind of cement do I use for this?
3. How do I even cut the stone? Tool?

Love to hear more advise.

Comment: Depends on the type of stone you're using.  If it's relatively soft stone, you can find rock-cutting attachments for angle grinders that would do the job. Usually they look metal and have something hard, like tiny industrial diamonds embedded in the metal.

Comment: Is it possible that the stone surface is a veneer?

Comment: It's real stone because I can see the pieces are very uneven ...